# Added default options to some controls when a value from dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two dropdown list and an inputbox. When a value from the dropdown list is selected a specific values should be preselected in the other two controls.

Here is my knockout code:

```
var viewModel = {
    templates: ko.observableArray(["Template1", "Template2"]),
    //when Template2 is selected Spanish should be preselected from the languages select list and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template2)
    //when Template1 is selected French should be preselected and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template1)
    languages: ko.observableArray(["English", "Spanish", "French"]),
    folderName: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here is my sample html code:

```
<select id="templates" data-bind="options: templates"></select>

<div>
<input data-bind="value: folderName"/>
</div>

<div>
<select id="languages" data-bind="options: languages"></select>
</div>
```

When Template2 is selected Spanish should be preselected from the languages select list and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template2).
 When Template1 is selected French should be preselected and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template1)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsyComa/Q8unN/19/

I am rather new to javascript and every help with working example will be greatly apreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more universal code. If you'll fill the `templateLanguageMap`with the template-language pairs, this code will solve your problem. You won't have to write a lot of `if` statements. Good Luck!

```
<select id="templates" data-bind="options: templates"
    onchange="onTemplateChange(value);"></select>

<div>
<input id="folderName"  data-bind="value: folderName"/>
</div>

<div>
<select id="languages" data-bind="options: languages"></select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var viewModel = {
        templates: ko.observableArray(["Template1", "Template2"]),
        //when Template2 is selected Spanish should be preselected from the languages select list and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template2)
        //when Template1 is selected French should be preselected and name of the template should be written in the folderName inputbox (Template1)
        languages: ko.observableArray(["English", "Spanish", "French"]),
        folderName: ko.observable()
    }

    var selectTemplates = document.getElementById('templates');
    var selectLanguages = document.getElementById('languages');
    var inputFolderName = document.getElementById('folderName');

    var templateLanguageMap = {"Template1":"Spanish", "Template2":"French"};

    onTemplateChange = function(value){
        inputFolderName.value = value;
        for ( var i = 0; i < selectLanguages.options.length; i++ ) {
            if ( selectLanguages.options[i].value == templateLanguageMap[value]) {
                selectLanguages.options[i].selected = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    onTemplateChange(selectTemplates.value);
```

Comment: thank You for your answer and sorry for the late response. It solves my issue. I wonder if there is a shorter way as there are about 70 values I should update on changing the template value and this is a lot of code...